# Simple efficient algorithm for dynamically maintaining max of special linear functions

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, optimization, online-algorithms

Given $n$ tuples $(k_i >0,a_i >0)$, is there any efficient algorithm that can dynamically track
$$
\max_{i=1,\cdots,n} \left\{k_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\right) - a_i\right\}
$$
in response to online updates to $a_i$? (in $\text{poly}(\log n)$ complexity per update).

I do have an algorithm in mind, which sees $k_i$s as the slope of lines and $-a_i$s as intercepts. The problem then can be reduced to maintaining the upper envelope of $n$ lines, which can be further reduced to a dynamic planar convex hull problem with established [algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002200008190012X) giving $\mathcal O(\log^2n)$ worst-case complexity per update.

I am not satisfied by my reduction because it ignores many specific structure of the problem that may be exploited. In addition, because I need to actually implement this algorithm in my project, a solution with dynamic convex hull is just way too tedious. Are there simpler algorithms for this problem with comparable complexity?

Comment: what is the desired space complexity?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I expect $n$ to be on the order of $10^5$ to $10^6$ so a space complexity of $\mathcal O(n \log n)$ or $\mathcal O(n \log^2 n)$ would be reasonable. $\mathcal O(n \sqrt n)$ would be acceptable too if that's necessary.